# Difference b/w String and encoded String

Tags: base64

is there any difference b/w normal String and a string which is come after converting an image in to Base64.encodeToString() i mean 
String temp=Base64.encodeToString(img, Base64.DEFAULT);

If we have a String str="Stack over flow";
then What is the difference b/w temp and str?
Please answer.Thanks

Comment: Well... they're different strings. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: actually there is no response When i am trying to print temp in toast